# Select a user from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can not solve the problem: In Firestore there is a collection of user, in which there are several documents with fields (email: "String", name: "String", password: "String"). In the textField, the email and password are entered, it is necessary to write a function that selects a specific user from Firestore from the entered data. The function entranceLogin ():

```
func entranceLogin() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else{
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }

    let values1 = [email]
    let values2 = [password]
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                db = document.value(forKey: "email = '\(values1)' && password = '\(values2)'") as! Firestore
                    print("\(db) => \(document.data())")
            }

             // self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what happens? what is expected and what has actually happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unsafe to store a password in the database the way you are doing it. Firebase already provides you with a login function

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in 
//.....
}
```

Then in your database instead of saving the password, just save the User UID for each of the users. Then you can fetch the user by using:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid else { return }
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments() { snapshot, error in 
// Do user fetching here
}
```